# Create a Facebook APP goes in circles back my page

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api

I have tried several times to create an APP for my business page and all it does is redirect me to my business page.

I also tried a few suggestions on here and got into a validation process. I have already validated by phone when I first signed up. I also tried the CC valid. Nothing.

Is this common? Do you have to have a personal account to create APPS? Anyone knows what gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use a personal account to create an app.

Comment: Can you upgrade your business page to a personal account? And what if you do not want a personal account? I am looking to use FB for business and personal.